# static? que es? y para que sirve?

Tags: c#, buenas-prácticas

Llevo un tiempo corto programando aplicaciones de escritorio en **C#**, y no comprendo la diferencia entre utilizar **static** en mis variables o funciones creadas, es decir:

```
private static String nombre_variable{get;set}
// cual es la diferencia entre
private String nombre_variable{get;set}
```

Lo mismo con las funciones:

```
public static int sumar(int a, int b){...}
//cual es la diferencia entre
public int sumar(int a, int b){...}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda iluminar sobre esto, ademas de decirme cual es la que me conviene utilizar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cuando usas `static` defines la variable, método o propiedad a nivel de clase y no de instancia, o sea no podrás aplicar conceptos de `programación orientado a objetos`

[static (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Si quieres crear diferentes objetos de una clase, no uses `static`, por ejemplo

```
public class Persona{
   public string Nombre {get;set;}
}
```

al definir esa clase podrías usar el `new`, o sea

```
Persona p1 = new Persona();
p1.Nombre = "Andres";
```

si creas una segunda instancia

```
Persona p2 = new Persona();
p2.Nombre = "Susana";
```

será independiente de la primera y ocupará un espacio de memoria separada.

Con las funciones sucede lo mismo, podrías definir

```
public class Persona{
   public string Nombre {get;set;}
   public string Apellido {get;set;}

   public string getFullName()
   {
       return $"{this.Apellido}, {this.Nombre}";
   }

}
```

veras que al no usar `static` puedo aplicar el `this`, el cual hace referencia a la instancia

```
Persona p1 = new Persona();
p1.Nombre = "Andres";
p1.Apellido = "Lopez";
textbox1.Text = p1.getFullName();
```

si usas `static` sería

```
public class Persona
{
   public string Nombre {get;set;}
   public string Apellido {get;set;}

   public static string getFullName(Persona p)
   {
       return $"{p.Apellido}, {p.Nombre}";
   }

}
```

al usar `static` tienes que pasar la instancia por parámetros

```
Persona p1 = new Persona();
p1.Nombre = "Andres";
p1.Apellido = "Lopez";
textbox1.Text = Persona.getFullName(p1);
```

para acceder a `getFullName` usas el nombre de la clase, no de la instancia

Comment: Mejor explicado imposible excelente

Answer (score 5):

> Traducción de la [respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9410742/8933039) por [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

[**`static`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) significa efectivamente "asociado con un tipo en lugar de cualquier instancia del tipo". Entonces hay un conjunto de variables estáticas para un tipo (dentro de un Dominio de aplicación) ya sea que tenga 0 instancias o un millón; no necesita una instancia para acceder a un miembro estático, etc.

El punto exacto de inicialización de las variables estáticas depende de si también hay un constructor estático o no, pero en términos generales es "una vez, generalmente antes de que ocurra algo significativo en la clase". ([Consulte esta publicación en el blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/) para obtener una descripción más detallada).

Mientras que los campos `readonly` pueden ser estáticos o de instancia (es decir, relacionados con el tipo o relacionados con una instancia del tipo), los valores `const` siempre son implícitamente estáticos (son constantes de tiempo de compilación, por lo que no tendría sentido tener una copia por ejemplo).

A veces puede verse `static`descrito como "compartido entre todas las instancias de un tipo" - Personalmente no me gusta esa descripción, ya que sugiere que debe haber al menos una instancia ... mientras que en realidad, no necesita ninguna instancia en orden usar un miembro estático. Prefiero pensar que están completamente separados, en lugar de ser "compartidos" entre instancias.

> **Mi aporte**: Resumiendo no se puede crear una instancia de una clase estática y solo puede contener miembros estáticos. Por lo tanto, las llamadas para una clase estática son como:

```
MiClaseStatic.MiMetodo(...) o MiClaseStatic.MiConstante.
```

Se puede crear una instancia de una clase no estática y puede contener miembros no estáticos (constructores de instancias, destructor, indexadores). Un miembro no estático de una clase no estática solo se puede llamar a través de un objeto:

```
MiClaseNoStatic x = new MiClaseNoStatic (...);
x.MiClaseNoStaticMetodo(...);
```

Ejemplo:

```
class MiClaseEjemplo {
    public int MetodoInstancia() { return 1; }
    public static int MetodoStatic() { return 2; }
}
```

Para llamar `MetodoInstancia`, necesitas una instancia de la clase:

```
MiClaseEjemplo instancia = new MiClaseEjemplo();
instancia.MetodoInstancia();   //Perfecto
instancia.MetodoStatic();     //No compilará

MiClaseEjemplo.MetodoInstancia();  //No compilará
MiClaseEjemplo.MetodoStatic();    //Perfecto
```

Answer (score 1):

Elegir entre hacer un método estático o no depende de varias condiciones.

Un método estático es también llamado método de clase (lo contrario sería un método de instancia) es decir que la lógica no depende de una instancia en particular sino que el comportamiento es genérico y solo depende de los argumentos que recibe y de otras variables estáticas.

**¿Cuándo usar métodos estáticos?**

Usa métodos estáticos para dejar en claro que el método puede llamarse en forma aislada.
También usas métodos estáticos en patrones como el [Singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb972272.aspx).

**¿Cuándo no usar métodos estáticos?**

Por su naturaleza uno no puede sobreescribir un método estático, porque justamente es de clase.
Una interface no puede tener declaraciones de métodos estáticos, por lo tanto si usas [inyección de dependencias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/communitydocs/net-dev/csharp/inyeccion-de-dependencias) no te conviene usar métodos estáticos ya que no vas a poder implementar Mocks sobre estos métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento un poco.
Cuando utilizas Static estas indicando que la ubicación en memoria de la variable será única sin importar cuantas instancias de esa clase se creen (objetos), como lo indica el libro Compiladores de Alfred V. Aho y demás:

"Una declaración como: public static int x; hace de x una variable de clase e indica que sólo hay una copia de x, sin importar cuántos objetos se creen de esta clase" (Compiladores: Principios, técnicas y herramientas. 2da Edic. pag 26)

Answer (score 0):

Un miembro estático de la clase es una propiedad, procedimiento o campo que comparten todas las instancias de una clase.

```
class ClassWithStaticMembers {
   public static int x = 5;

   public static int StaticMethod (int x) {
       int result = x * 2;

       return result;
   }
}
class OtherClass {

    int x = ClassWithStaticMembers.x;

    x = ClassWithStaticMembers.StaticMethod (x);
}
```

Como se ve en el ejemplo todos los miembros estáticos son accesibles desde otras clases sin necesidad de instanciar la clase.

Ahora bien esto sirve en el caso de que la clase pueda tener distintas instancias de esta, pero ciertos miembros necesitas que sean accesibles en todo el código (por ejemplo una variable estática que almacene el numero total de empleados que se han instanciado).

En el caso de que no necesites crear instancias de la clase, sino que más bien esta, se adecúe a lo que se conoce como una ***"clase de utilidad"***, es cuando debes usar la palabra clave static con la clase, teniendo en cuenta que eso supone no poder crear instancias, y tener que declarar todos los miembros de esta como estáticos.

```
public static class StaticMathsClass {
      public const double PI = 3.14159265359;

      public static float Sum (float x, float y) {
          float result = x + y;

          return result;
      }

      public static float AreaCircle (float r) {
          float result = (float) PI * (r * r);

          return result;
      }
}

class OtherClass {
   double pi = StaticMathsClass.PI;

   float x = StaticMathsClass.Sum (5, 6);

   float a = StaticMathsClass.AreaCircle (12.56f);
}
```

Podemos ver que no solo se puede usar static sino que también acepta constantes (const).

Una útlima cosa a recalcar es que los miembros estáticos no pueden tener acceso a las propiedades, los campos o los métodos no estáticos.

Un saludo, y espero haber ayudado :)