# ¿Por qué el valor de esta variable no estática en una clase se pierde?, C#

Tags: c#, clase, variables-globales

Voy a ejemplificar el problema de la siguiente manera:

Tengo la siguiente `Clase` **Utilidad** no `static` en la cual tengo dos variables globales una estática `codigo_usuario` y otra no estática `codigo`.

```
public class Utilidad
{
    private string codigo = string.Empty;

    public string Codigo
    {
        get { return codigo; }
        set { codigo = value; }
    }

    private static string codigo_usuario = string.Empty;

    public static string Codigo_usuario
    {
        get { return codigo_usuario; }
        set { codigo_usuario = value; }
    }
}
```

A estas dos variables les asigno un valor de la siguiente forma desde el primer formulario:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void entrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Utilidad clase = new Utilidad();
         clase.Codigo = "AC001"; //Asigno valor a la variable no estatica. 
         Utilidad.Codigo_usuario = "AC001"; //Asigno valor a la variable estatica.

         Form_Principal formulario = new Form_Principal();
         this.Hide();
         formulario.ShowDialog();
         this.Close();
    }
}
```

Pero cuando intento obtener el valor de esas variables de la clase en otro formulario, la variable **no estatica** esta vacia.

```
public partial class Form_Principal : Form
{
    public Form_Principal ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void mostrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Utilidad clase = new Utilidad();

          MessageBox.Show("Codigo: " + clase.Codigo +
                          "\n Codigo Usuario: " + Utilidad.Codigo_usuario);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿A qué se debe que la variable no estática `codigo` no mantenga su valor?**

Comment: Estás haciendo un `new Utilidad()` antes de mostrarlo, por lo que lógicamente estará vacío. Deberías utilizar la variable `clase` que has rellenado en el otro método.

Comment: A que estás creando una nueva instancia de la clase y su valor por defecto es `string.Empty` y el atributo estático se cambio en el botón entrar cuando hace `Utilidad.Codigo_usuario = "AC001";`

Comment: posible pregunta relacionada [static? que es? y para que sirve?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152642/static-que-es-y-para-que-sirve/152656#152656)

Comment: @Wyrncael y como uso el valor de la variable desde el otro método si son formularios distintos? tendría que hacer esa variable publica, y la idea es tener una única variable para acceder desde los demás formularios, cómo debo hacer? Cuál sería la forma correcta?

Comment: @Dev.Joel, si vi esa publicación [static? que es? y para que sirve?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152650/69447) incluso coloqué una respuesta. Entonces en este caso debería usar la variable `static`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe a que la propiedad que no es estatica pertenece al objeto. 
De modo que cuando usas la funcion `entrar_Click` estas **creando un objeto nuevo** con el operador `new` al cual le asignas un vlaor para su propiedad `Codigo`, y cuando llamas a la funcion `mostrar_Click` estas **creando otro objeto nuevo**(al usar el `new`) con su respectiva propiedad `Codigo` en blanco.

Como ambos objetos pertenecen a la misma clase, estos si comparten su propiedad estatica ya que esa es comun entre todos los objetos de la clase.

Comment: Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo entonces?

Comment: Bueno, me estaba limitando a contestar tu pregunta, pero hay varias maneras de hacerlo, la verdad no se como sea el proyecto entero, pero la manera mas sencilla quizas sea hacer que ambas propiedades sean estaticas, o implementar un patron singleton, hay muchas maneras de hacerlo realmente y no se cual es la que mas te convenga

Comment: De acuerdo, de momento optare por utilizarla `static`

Answer (score 1):

Eso pasa porque estas creando una instancia nueva de la clase Utilidad y como es nueva el campo Código está vacío porque no se la ha dado un valor. En todo caso para compartir el campo Código entro los formulario tendrías que cambiarlo a que sea estático también.

Y en tu clase FormPrincipal, harías esto:

```
   MessageBox.Show("Codigo: " + Utilidad.Codigo +
                      "\n Codigo Usuario: " + Utilidad.Codigo_usuario);
```

Eso si variables estáticas no es la forma más recomendable para compartir información entre clases. Tal vez algo como esto te serviría:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171925.aspx