# cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms

Me sale este error pero no se cual sera el error solo lo subraya en color azul

```
private void NewConfiguration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



          this.Minute = this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupMinutes;
           this.Command = this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupCommands;
           this.TxtMinuteGrouping.Text = (this.Minute).ToString();
            this.TxtCommandGrouping.Text = (this.Command).ToString();
           // this.TxtGroupingRelease.Text = this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.IsReleaseGroupedComms;
           //if (this.bizKitchenConfiguration.IsConfirmsRelease.Equals("SI")) this.CkbReleaseCommand.Checked = true;
          // else this.CkbReleaseCommand.Checked = false;
           this.Location = new Point(
                ((this.Owner.Width - this.Width) / 2),
                ((this.Owner.Height - this.Height) / 2)
            );
        }
```

Las lineas comentadas son donde me da el error, pienso que debe ser algo sobre el tipo de dato de IsReleaseGroupedComms ya que en varias partes me da error en ese dato por que los enteros los agarra bien, lo que hago es capturar el valor de un txt para posteriormente guardarlo en la bd mysql

BizKitchenNewConfiguration.cs

```
namespace Parrot.Kitchen.Business.Entities.Model
{
     public class BizKitchenNEWConfiguration
    {
        public int GroupMinutes { get; set; }
        public int GroupCommands { get; set; }
        public static string IsReleaseGroupedComms { get; set; }
        public static string IsConfirmsRelease { get; set; }
        public static string IsReleased { get; set; }
     //   public string IsReleasedGroupedComms { get; set; }

        public string IsReleasedGroupedComms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mi interfaz es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que trato de hacer es programar el boton de  guardar, para que se guarde # minutos, # comandas y liberar comanda, en la base de datos kitchen

```
BizCall(
             new Action(() =>
                 {
                     result = crudFunction.GetKitchenParameter("ReleaseGroupedComms", bizKitchenConfiguration.ScreenId);
                 }
             )
            );

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                var section = result.Split('|');

               // BizKitchenNEWConfiguration.IsReleaseGroupedComms = section[1];
            }
            else
            {
              //  BizKitchenNEWConfiguration.IsReleaseGroupedComms = "NO";
            }
```

La parte comentada es la de los errroes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si defines propiedades en una clase no deberias tener el `static` ya que no seran propiedades de instancia sino que seran de clase.

En la clase `BizKitchenNEWConfiguration` quita el `static` de las propiedades

```
public class BizKitchenNEWConfiguration
{
    public int GroupMinutes { get; set; }
    public int GroupCommands { get; set; }
    public string IsReleaseGroupedComms { get; set; }
    public string IsConfirmsRelease { get; set; }
    public string IsReleased { get; set; }

    public string IsReleasedGroupedComms { get; set; }
}
```

de esta forma podras acceder a los valores de la instancia que creas de la clase

Recomendaria leas un poco de teoria

[Utilizar propiedades (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

alli menciona

> Una propiedad puede declararse como una propiedad estática mediante la palabra clave static. Esto hace que la propiedad esté disponible para los autores de la llamada en cualquier momento, aunque no exista ninguna instancia de la clase

[Clases estáticas y sus miembros (Guía de programación de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Comment: Pues debo decir que los errores aumentaron ahora sale uno aqui que se llama, " An object reference is requiered for the non-static field, method, or property, la parte del codigo la agregue arriba

Comment: No puedes usar `BizKitchenNEWConfiguration.IsReleaseGroupedComms`, porque no defines la instancia cuando usas el "new", no puedes mezclar los conceptos. En `NewConfiguration_Load` usas `this.bizKitchenConfiguration`, porque despues dejas de usarlo

Comment: Hablas de que le tengo que cambiar nombre a  **BizKitchenNEWConfiguration** o que debo de instanciarla ?

Comment: partamos de la base, sabes lo que es una instancia ? porque creo que el problema no esta en el codigo, sino en los conceptos, deberias leer algo de POO (programacion orientada a objetos)

Comment: @AlejandroOlivares hace un par de dias que le das vuelta al mismo codigo y siempre son los mismos errores. Porque usas static? Sabes la diferencia entre instacia y clase? me parece que deberias revisar esos conceptos, o hacer preguntas para clarificar esos temas. Sabes para que se usa static?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini le estaba poniendo exactamente lo mismo, porque es la tercer o cuarta pregunta con exactamente el mismo problema, y me parece que su confusion viene por lo que vos decis.

Comment: Hace tiempo se hizo una pregunta sobre cuándo usar static, y la respondió muy bien @LeandroTuttini, te dejo el enlace para que la veas y aclares tus ideas   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152642/static-que-es-y-para-que-sirve

Comment: @LeandroTuttini eres muy bueno, ya lo logre instanciandola, gracias a todos, prometo mejorar

Comment: Yo supongo que son errores que se traen de empezar todo con aplicaciones de consola, donde generalmente la clase Program es estática, y de ahí se cree que las cosas (métodos, propiedades, etc) deben ser estáticos.

Comment: @AlejandroOlivares si esta respuesta te ayudó, considera marcarla como aceptada. Asi agradeces a la persona que te ayuda, y a otros que en el futuro puedan tener un problema similar.