# ¿En qué casos exactamente se puede usar el static en c# y por qué usarlo?

Tags: c#

Bueno en mi caso he visto que normalmente al static usarlo en el class program del proyecto, pero no entiendo el porqué

Comment: Sabes que hace static?

Comment: Me pregunto si esto no derivará en una serie de opiniones... ya que `static` se puede utilizar en muchos casos, dependerá del criterio de cada quién, ¿no?

Comment: en que casos usarlo y porque??? seria el mismo problema con si debo usar public o private.. tal vez tenes razon @jachguate

Comment: la respuesta seria algo asi como cuando quieras.. y porque te convenia.. no entenderia de otra respuesta que no fuera basada en opiniones

Comment: estoy recién en programación y pues en el curso que llevo solo he visto usar el static en la parte del program, más no en otras del proyecto. Quisiera ver más utilidades y su porqué

Comment: @gbianchi, Creo que esta pregunta está duplicada, [Ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/152642/182188)

Comment: @Pablo, efectivamente...